# I need some help getting the connection string correct to connect Golang to AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, database, go, amazon-rds

I have been looking and looking on how to connect a Golang application to a MySQL database (I am using the MyMySQL library with the database/sql interface). If I use the none native version not the database/sql interface I can get the connection to work perfectly and perform queries. If I try to connect using the database/sql go interface (which I think is the best way to interface to MySQL?) then I just cannot get the connection to work? The error I keep getting is 'Wrong database part of URI'?????

Sorry for the variable names but I have been trying and trying to get various versions working so the names are a bit screwy sorry again.

I am grateful for any help understanding my problem, thanks again for your time.

[image: The go code which I am using to produce the connection string.]

Comment: Please, don't include [screen shots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mymysql package defines a non-standard URI format for accessing MySQL when using the `database/sql` package (from [their readme](https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql#example-7---use-databasesql-with-mymysql-driver)):

```
[PROTOCOL_SPECIFIC*]DBNAME/USER/PASSWD
```

So in your case you'd want to change your format string to this:

```
connectionStr := fmt.Sprintf("tcp:%s:3306,%s/%s/%s", database, dbname, user, password)
```

The reason you are seeing the error you are seeing is that the `Open` function splits the URI into 3 parts based on `/` (see [this](https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql/blob/master/godrv/driver.go#L359-L362)) and fails if it finds less than three parts.

On a side note, unless you have a strong reason for choosing `mymysql` you should consider using [go-sql-driver/mysql](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) as it is an excellent MySQL driver and supports standard MySQL DSNs like you already have defined.

Comment: Andrew thank you for your time is has been very much appreciated! I messed about until 1am and I did get everything working using the library you mentioned 'go-sql-driver' which worked straight away with as you said the standard connection string format. I am going to take your valuable advice and use the 'go-sql-driver' instead as it appears to just be a more standard solid solution. Many thanks again Andrew.